# Deploying to Heroku with Laravel Docker Container times out

Tags: laravel, docker, heroku

I am pretty new to both Heroku and Docker, so please forgive any redundancy and thanks for any help I can get.

I have a Docker container that is running fine locally. Here is my config:

DockerFile:

```
FROM php:7
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN composer install
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8181
EXPOSE 8181
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8009:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file: .env
    working_dir: /app
    command: bash -c 'php artisan migrate && php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0'
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD={pass}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE={dbname}
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD={pass}
    volumes:
      - ./data/:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8090:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: {mypass}
```

I am deploying to heroku as follows:

```
#heroku container:login

#heroku container:push web --app bmbx-inventory

#heroku container:release web --app bmbx-inventory
```

These all run with no errors.

Here are the logs from Heroku:

```
2021-04-05T00:20:09.317985+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c php\ artisan\ serve\ --host\=0.0.0.0\ --port\=8181`
2021-04-05T00:20:12.468981+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting Laravel development server: http://0.0.0.0:8181
2021-04-05T00:20:12.976634+00:00 app[web.1]: [Mon Apr  5 00:20:12 2021] PHP 7.4.16 Development Server (http://0.0.0.0:8181) started
2021-04-05T00:21:09.679616+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-04-05T00:21:09.731878+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-04-05T00:21:09.829583+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-04-05T00:21:09.924793+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: Here's an additional error if that helps: 2021-04-05T00:25:54.895025+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=bmbx-inventory.herokuapp.com request_id=b3a29ff2-50f8-402b-88cd-58472e5b8df7 fwd="99.14.202.67" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Heroku you need to bind to the (dynamic) port provided by Heroku at runtime, which you can find in the `$PORT` env variable.
You **cannot hardcode** the port to 8081 (or any other port) as you would do on your local dev environment

```
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=$PORT
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Now I am on to the next issue, but unrelated. :-)